# EditText android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, keyboard, android-edittext

I create an application on android studio,I have 4 EditText to write an IP Address, I want to move automaticly the cursor to the following EditText when I write 3 numbers in an EditText. How to do Thanks You?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this.

1. Set the inputType and maxLength attributes in xml of each of these EditTexts.

   android:inputType="number"
   android:maxLength="3"

Next, define the next focus item:

```
android:nextFocusRight="id"
```

2. Alternately you can add a textChangedListener for each of the EditText's:

   editText1.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);

   private final TextWatcher mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

   ```
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
           int count) {

   }

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
           int after) {

   }

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       if (s.length() == 3) {
           // editText2.requestFocus();
   }
   ```

   };

Try this, also u need to add two attributes to the xml and each views as well:

```
android:focusable="true";
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: Thy first way seems too correct but I try it and dont work :(

Comment: @pape, paste the full xml here

Comment: I put it in comment below. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
You have to constantly check the input of each editText in 
onTextChanged method, To do this, you have to implement 
addTextChangedListener on each editText and check the charSequence if 
equal = 3.

for example

    yourFirstEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

     if(charSequence.toString().length() == 3) {
      //call next forcus
      yourSecondEditText.requestFocus();
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

    yourSecondEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

     if(charSequence.toString().length() == 3) {
      //call next forcus
      yourThirdEditText.requestFocus();
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

//you don't need to do that for the last editText
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/AbsoluteLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:paddingEnd="3dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/IdOK"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="123dp"
        android:layout_y="256dp"
        android:text="OK" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="178dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:text="Saisir l&apos;adresse IP"
        android:id="@+id/saisiAdIp"
        android:layout_x="96dp"
        android:layout_y="105dp"
        android:textSize="21dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/AdIpsaisi1"
        android:layout_x="35dp"
        android:layout_y="146dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/AdIpsaisi2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/AdIpsaisi2"
        android:layout_x="103dp"
        android:layout_y="146dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:nextFocusRight="@+id/AdIpsaisi3"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/AdIpsaisi3"
        android:layout_x="170dp"
        android:layout_y="146dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:nextFocusRight="@+id/AdIpsaisi4"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/AdIpsaisi4"
        android:layout_x="240dp"
        android:layout_y="146dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="."
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_x="96dp"
        android:layout_y="165dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="."
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_x="165dp"
        android:layout_y="165dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="."
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_x="231dp"
        android:layout_y="165dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="184dp"
        android:layout_height="87dp"
        android:text="Adresse IP incorrect"
        android:id="@+id/erreursaisi"
        android:layout_x="116dp"
        android:layout_y="374dp"
        android:textSize="30dp" />


</AbsoluteLayout>
```